# CAsyncSocket without subclassing?

Tags: c++, sockets, winapi, mfc, network-programming

I'm looking for a way to use CAsyncSocket without subclassing it. In all the examples and tutorials I've found so far they subclass from it and I would like to avoid it.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

`CAsyncSocket` is designed to be used by subclassing it. It has virtual methods - `OnConnect`, `OnReceive` that must be overridden by a sub class in order for application code to handle the events.

Comment: thank you, so is there no way at all  to use it without sub-classing?

Comment: Not without rendering it essentially a plain CSocket.

Answer (score 1):

There is no requirement to derive from [CAsyncSocket](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3d46645f.aspx) to use it, although clients usually do. If you do not derive (and implement the callback handlers) it's virtually impossible to use the socket in an asynchronous way.

`CAsyncSocket` is like any other C++ class, and can be instantiated in much the same way (either on the stack with automatic storage duration, or - more commonly - in the free store with dynamic storage duration). The MSDN offers a tutorial on using a 'naked' `CAsyncSocket`: [Windows Sockets: Using Class CAsyncSocket](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t7a47kk4.aspx).

Comment: Cheers mate, I guess I already saw that tutorial. The problem with that is that it doesn't explain at all how to use it in conjunction with other classes

Comment: @user3770392: That's simply because there is nothing particularly interesting to know about using `CAsyncSocket` in conjunction with other classes. It's just your average C++ class. What specifically do you need to know?

Comment: I don't know if you are familiar to Qt, I would like to do something like that, e.g. when a packet arrives, another method is invoked. I would like to avoid subclassing whenever I can.

Comment: @user3770392: And how exactly had you planned to get notified about incoming data without deriving from `CAsyncSocket` and implementing your own notification handlers? Since you keep repeating that you would like to avoid deriving from a class it's beginning to sound like you are really trying to avoid learning C++.

Comment: there's always to learn for sure, but there are many ways in C++ to avoid sub-classing. Just passing a function pointer or a functor would have been ok for me

Comment: Anyway, I'll try it to look better into the msdn documentation.. the best thing is always read more

Comment: I don't see **any** reason to avoid deriving from `CAsyncSocket` (and you haven't really put anything forth either). It is part of `CAsyncSocket`s protocol to derive from it, and handle notifications in virtual overrides. If you don't want to derive from `CAsyncSocket` then there really is no reason to use `CAsyncSocket` to begin with. You could just as well go with Windows Sockets 2, with a flat C interface.

Comment: I guess I will look into Windows Sockets 2 then, thank you again for your suggestions.